# SQLITE CONSTRAINT EXCEPTION Error code 19

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-insert

I am working on an Android contact list application. Below is my Dbhandler class. When I want to insert a new contact into my database and I press the save button it gives me an error:

```
Error inserting Name=f HOME=00 Phone=a Address=b android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

Please help me out ,i have also attached my logcat.

Source code:

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DB_Version = 1;

    private static final String DB_Name = "Places";

    protected static final String Places_Table = "Places";
    private String DB_PATH=""; 

    String name, Address, Website,ID;
    //WebpreneurActivity Contact;
 public static final String Key_ID = "ID";
 public static final String Key_Name = "Name";
 public static final String Key_Phone = "Phone";
 public  static final String Key_Address = "Address";
 public static final String Key_Website = "Website";
 public  static final String Key_Home = "HOME";
 public static final String PROJECTION[] = {
    Key_ID,
    Key_Name,
    Key_Address,
    Key_Phone,
    Key_Home
};

    String CREATE_PLACES_TABLE = "create table if not exists Places_Table (id integer primary key ,"+
            "name VARCHAR not null, phone VARCHAR not null, address VARCAHR not null, website VARCHAR not null,Home VARCHAR not null)";

     private final Context context;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_Version);
        this.context = context;  
         DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/"; 
        Log.d("database1" ,"4");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{
            Log.d("DB", "DB creationnewwwww");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE  " + Places_Table + " (" +
                        Key_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"+
                        Key_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        Key_Phone + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        Key_Address + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        Key_Website + " TEXT," +
                        Key_Home + " TEXT)");
                Log.d("DB", "DB creationnewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.d("DB", "DB creation excptionhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exists" + Places_Table);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void open()
    {Log.d("DB", "DB creation 9");
     db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //onCreate(db);
    Log.d("DB", "DB creation 9");
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_Name;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() { 
       if(db != null)
            db.close(); 
        super.close(); 
    }


    public void createRow(String name, String address, String Phone, String home)
    {SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(Key_Name, name);
        initialValues.put(Key_Address, address);
        initialValues.put(Key_Phone, Phone);
        initialValues.put(Key_Home, home);
                //pass the initialValues to the database to insert the row
        Log.d(Key_Home, home);
        db.insert(Places_Table, null, initialValues);
        Log.d("Your Location4", "okna:");
    }

        public void deleteRow(long rowId){
        db.delete(Places_Table, Key_ID+"="+rowId,null);
    }

        public boolean updateRow (long rowId, String name, String address, String Phone, String home){
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(Key_Name, name);
        args.put(Key_Address, address);
        args.put(Key_Phone, Phone);
        args.put(Key_Home, home);
        return db.update(Places_Table, args, Key_ID +"="+ rowId, null)>0;
    }
        public Cursor fetchRow(long rowId) throws SQLException{
            Cursor result = db.query( Places_Table, null, 
                    Key_ID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null,null);
            if ((result.equals(rowId)) || !result.isFirst()) {
                throw new SQLException("No note matching ID: " + rowId);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public Cursor fetchAllRows(){
            Log.d("Your Location4", "ok99:");
            return db.query(Places_Table, PROJECTION, 
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        }
}
 Here is my logcat

01-27 19:00:21.664: D/database1(15280): b4
01-27 19:00:21.674: D/database1(15280): button3
01-27 19:00:21.684: D/database1(15280): button4
01-27 19:00:21.714: D/database1(15280): button5
01-27 19:00:21.714: D/database1(15280): button5
01-27 19:00:36.519: W/KeyCharacterMap(15280): Can't open keycharmap file
01-27 19:00:36.519: W/KeyCharacterMap(15280): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/ux500-ske-keypad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='ux500-ske-keypad'
01-27 19:00:36.529: W/KeyCharacterMap(15280): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-27 19:00:40.543: E/what(15280): result set
01-27 19:00:40.583: D/Your Location4(15280): jj:
01-27 19:00:40.583: D/HOME(15280): 6r
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280): Error inserting Name=g HOME=6r Phone=64 Address=f
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java:61)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1590)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1434)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at com.webpreneur_contactlist.DBHandler.createRow(DBHandler.java:154)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at com.webpreneur_contactlist.WebpreneurActivity.onActivityResult(WebpreneurActivity.java:145)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-27 19:00:40.613: E/Database(15280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 19:00:40.613: D/Your Location4(15280): okna:
01-27 19:00:40.623: D/Your Location4(15280): ok90:
01-27 19:00:40.623: D/Your Location4(15280): ok6:
01-27 19:00:40.623: D/Your Location4(15280): ok99:
01-27 19:00:40.623: D/AndroidRuntime(15280): Shutting down VM
01-27 19:00:40.623: W/dalvikvm(15280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d578)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.webpreneur_contactlist/com.webpreneur_contactlist.WebpreneurActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1238)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1197)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1279)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at com.webpreneur_contactlist.DBHandler.fetchAllRows(DBHandler.java:181)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at com.webpreneur_contactlist.WebpreneurActivity.fillData(WebpreneurActivity.java:76)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at com.webpreneur_contactlist.WebpreneurActivity.onActivityResult(WebpreneurActivity.java:147)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
01-27 19:00:40.623: E/AndroidRuntime(15280):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Might be entering a null value to a field which you declared as not null

Comment: missing `contentValues.put(Key_Home, home);`

Comment: Great use of logs. "DB creation excptionhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"

Comment: Did you ever use `CREATE_PLACES_TABLE` in an older version of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.webpreneur_contactlist/com.webpreneur_contactlist.WebpreneurActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
```

Seems that you didn't open the connection to database. You need to call you `open()` method first in your `WebpreneurActivity`.

Comment: In my webpreneuractivity class i first called dbHelper = new DBHandler(this); then i called dbHelpler.open();

Comment: But seems that some how database is not opened. Try to put calling of you open() method in try-catch block catching SQLException exception and see if you will catch any exception. Could you try this and post the result?